# Import "spacy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I am new to python and I don't have much experience in constructing a good working directory. But in my past experience working with installed packages through pip, I don't have any issues.

I am trying to download, install and import spacy. According to my pip list, I see the spacy package is successfully downloaded. But when I try to create a python document on MS visual studio code, running the code `import spacy` in my terminal, it says

> Import "spacy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports).

When I run it on command, it says:

```
2021-07-10 15:41:04.164329: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-07-10 15:41:04.164530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling eager execution
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling v2 tensorshape
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling resource variables
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling tensor equality
INFO:tensorflow:Enabling control flow v2
```

I wonder if anyone is having a clue on what is going on.

Comment: Did you notice this remark in the log: *Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine*? The message *could not be resolved* is a technical shortcoming of the linter and happens quite frequently when a library module is written in C/C++ and there is no Python implementation to check your code against.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create a `requirements.txt` file where all your installs are listed. Every time you add something, update the requirements file by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then when you activate your virtual environment, you can just run `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt` to fix similar issues with missing imports, etc...

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solved this question by setting up a virtual environment in the directory I'm working on, installing the packages I needed for the project.

Answer (score 0):

### Debug:

#### Terminal

1. Create a virtual environment:

```
python -m venv .env
```

2. Activate the virtual environment:

```
source .env/bin/activate  # Unix/Linux/Mac
.env\Scripts\activate.bat  # Windows
```

3. or, activate conda (if not already activated):

```
conda create -n venv
conda activate venv
```

4. Install the `spacy-llm` package using `conda`:

```
conda install spacy-llm
```

5. Validate installation

```
python -m spacy validate
```

#### In VScode:

- `cmd + p`
- `> Python: Select interpreter` + `return`
- select interpreter at workspace level: venv env python 3.11.3
  [virtual environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRnyy.png)

#### References:

- https://github.com/patmejia/spacy-llm/issues/1
- [Import could not be resolved/could not be resolved from source Pylance in VS Code using Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486207/import-could-not-be-resolved-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-in-vs-cod)
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3035
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/236
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2288
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3452