# import "dotenv" could not be resolved

Tags: python, python-dotenv

I am making a program in python that I plan to host on github. I have a `.env` file containing an api token. I tried to import it into my code like so:

first i installed the `python-dotenv` library by typing `pip install python-dotenv` in the command prompt. `python-dotenv` shows when i type `pip list`.

then in my code:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

example = os.getenv('TOKEN')
```

`from dotenv import load_dotenv` gives the error `Import "dotenv" could not be resolved Pylancereport (MissingImports)` and my code will not run. Is there anything i'm doing wrong? How can i fix it?

Comment: is it vscode issue? the check https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/vscode+python+import+could+not+be+resolved

Comment: I think that the problem is that `load_dotenv` can't be imported from `dotenv` because it doesn't exist on the package `__init__.py` file.

I replicated your steps and got the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv` (I used vim).

Comment: Oh I think that I have found the problem: you installed `python-env` instead of `python-dotenv`. Do a `pip install python-dotenv`. Execute your code again and it should work.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486207/import-could-not-be-resolved-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-in-vs-cod

Comment: i think it is a vscode issue. i'm looking into it now

Comment: i did install the correct library, it was a post typo sorry

Answer (score 11):

It seems you have installed `python-env`, when you really wanted to install `python-dotenv`. The former doesn't have the function you are trying to use on it's `__init__.py` file, that's why `Pylancereport` can't resolve it.

**Solution:**
Do a `pip install python-dotenv`. Execute your code again and it should work.

Comment: i did install the correct library, it was a typo in the post. sorry

Comment: reinstalling the virutalenv solves my issue

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that helped me was the complete removal of the virtual environment, creating a new one and installing requirements.txt (of course with python-dotenv inside)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm new to Python and this helped to fix the missing imports issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and after little bit of researching I found that the issue was in **using the system python interpreter** instead of **python interpreter inside the virtual environment** which I have created. Since I was using VSCode editor.
Therefore, following steps resolved the issue.

Step1: Hit Ctrl+P and type `>Python: Select Interpreter`
click the 'Python: Select Interpreter' which appear in the search bar.
[image]

Step2:Click the `Enter interpreter path`
[image]

Step3:
Now browse your system and select the python interpreter inside your virtual enviroment folter `venvFoderName/Scripts/Python`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the dotenv library folder, load_dotenv() is in the main.py file.

To properly import, you should do

```
from dotenv.main import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

will work.