# How can I fix this Import problem with vsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, import, request

I'm having a little problem. I would like to import bs4 and request on my vscode file but I can't in tells me that there is a missign module source. I tried to change the interpreter but when I do it only one of them is recognized. So if anyone knows how I can import both of them I would gradely appreciate, thanks.

[The error message that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2fTT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install projected related extension then try to import.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post [regarding the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486207/import-could-not-be-resolved-could-not-be-resolved-from-source-pylance-in-vs-cod). Also [this guide](https://dev.to/climentea/how-to-solve-pylance-missing-imports-in-vscode-359b) could hold the answer to your problem.

You may have installed the libraries inside a virtual environment and you are using a python interpreter that is not inside the environment.

Edit: It could be that just one of your libraries is inside (or outside) the environment.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, perform the following steps:

1. Open the Command Palette by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on your keyboard.
2. In the Command Palette, select <kbd>Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window</kbd>.

This problem usually happens when you make or activate a virtual environment and vscode hasn't read it yet and needs a refresh or restart, also make sure you are using the correct interpreter that have the project dependencies installed(Virtual Environment maybe).