# Why doesn't Django recognize create_user() when I want to create a User?

Tags: python, django, request

I want to create **User** with `User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)` where User imported from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` but Django doesn't recognize `create_user()` and When I want to definition of it VsCode says:`No Definition found for 'create_user'`.

I use Django 4.0.4 and python 3.10.4

Comment: Does this answer to your question ? [Import could not be resolved/could not be resolved from source Pylance in VS Code using Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10 Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68495684/14457833)

Comment: Is it just VS Code complaining or do you actually get an error? Django is very dynamic and IDEs quite often fail to realize that.